# Javascript Fetch not getting a response

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm invoking an authentication service via javascript fetch to get an access token.  The service is a simple RESTful call.  I can see the call is successful using fiddler (with a 200 response and json data).  However the fetch response never seems to get invoked.  Below is a snippet:

```
const AUTHBODY = `grant_type=password&username=${username}&password=${password}&scope=roles offline_access profile`
const AUTHHEADER = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})

const CONFIG = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: AUTHHEADER,
    body: AUTHBODY
}

fetch('http://localhost:23461/connect/token', CONFIG).then(function(response) {
    console.log('response = ' + response)
    return response.json()
}).then(function(json) {
    console.log('json data = ' + json)
    return json
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('error = ' + error)
})
```

When executing the fetch above none of the console.logs gets executed... seems to just hang.  But fiddler tells otherwise.  Any ideas?

Comment: fetch is poorly supported, did you check that your browser supports it? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: also, that url should be in quotes...

Comment: Are you able to test that the server is actually responding with something? Perhaps with a tool like Postman.

Comment: Yes I've testing using fiddler solely and then fiddler monitoring http traffic when I use that javascript fetch().  The calls are all good, just nothing coming back as a response in the fetch

Comment: This is what fiddler sees as the response header that the fetch invoked:   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 1966
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Expires: -1
Server: Kestrel
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcbXZcd29ya3NwYWNlc1xCQ1NDeWJlclxCb3JkZXJlYXVcQkNTLkN5YmVyLkJvcmRlcmVhdVxhdXRoZW50aWNhdGU=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 08 Aug 2016 16:53:09 GMT

Comment: what browser you are using?

Comment: both chrome 52.0.2743.116 m and firefox 47.0

Comment: You have an invisible Unicode "ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER" character (char code 8204) after the `m` in `...Rlcm...` in your `X-SourceFiles` header. This appears to be causing issues; at least it did when I tested it on http://www.test-cors.org/ (To demonstrate this, copy the `Rlcm‌​` from your comment (or from any instance in *this* comment), and paste it into your browser's JS console and do  `"Rlcm‌".length` and/or `"Rlcm‌".charCodeAt(4)`)

Comment: Just used test-cors.org testing my localhost.  Seems to work ok:  Sending POST request to http://localhost:23461/connect/token
, with custom headers: Content-Type
Fired XHR event: loadstart
Fired XHR event: readystatechange
Fired XHR event: readystatechange
Fired XHR event: progress
Fired XHR event: readystatechange
Fired XHR event: load

XHR status: 200
XHR status text: OK
XHR exposed response headers:
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: -1


Fired XHR event: loadend

Comment: @LosMorales I was testing with the "Local" option, using the invisible character in a response header: http://www.test-cors.org/#?client_method=POST&client_credentials=false&server_enable=true&server_status=200&server_credentials=false&server_response_headers=X-SourceFiles%3A%20invisiblecharhere%3D%3Em%E2%80%8C%0A&server_tabs=local But I'm not sure why test-cors.org works for your localhost (which should send that invisible character); that seems very strange.

Comment: Also, what if you add a `.catch(function(err) { console.log(err); }` to the end of the promise chain? Does that run?

Comment: no, no console.log statements were executed.  It's like after the fetch call nothing gets executed after the 1st then()...

Comment: having same issue , @LosMorales if you got a solution then please answer it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably met with the CORS origin policy problem. To tackle this you need some rights to access the server side of your API. In particular, you need to add a line in the header of php or another server endpoint:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
//or
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com');

// Reading JSON POST using PHP
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonObj = json_decode($json);

// Use $jsonObj
print_r($jsonObj->message);

...
// End php
?>
```

Also, make sure NOT to have in the header of your server endpoint:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true);
```

Model of working fetch code with POST request is:

```
const data = {
        message: 'We send a message to the backend with fetch()'
    };
const endpoint = 'http://example.com/php/phpGetPost.php';

fetch(endpoint, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then(function(response) {
    console.info('fetch()', response);
    return response;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let arr = []
let page = 1
let recBoxs = document.querySelector('.recent-boxs')
let loadElement = document.querySelector('.load-more')
let search = document.querySelector('.search-input')
let searchBtn = document.querySelector('.search-btn')
function getDataJson() {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/services?_page=${page}&_limit=3`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            arr.push(data);
            data.forEach(element => {
                recBoxs.innerHTML += `
        <div class="recent-box">
            <i onclick="addFavorite(${element.id})" class="fa-regular fa-heart" ></i>
            <div class="recent-image"><img src="${element.images}" alt="Image"></div>
            <div class="rec-box-p">${element.date}</div>
            <div class="rec-box-h2">${element.title}</div>
            <div class = "rec-box-btns">
             <button class="delete" onclick="boxsDelete(${element.id})">
             <i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
             <button class = "update"><a href = "./update.html?id=${element.id}" target = "_blank"><i class="fa-solid fa-pencil"></i></a></button>
             <button class = "cart"><a href = "./details.html?id=${element.id}"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></a></button>
            </div>
        </div>
            `
            });
            return arr.flat();
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
}
function boxsDelete(id) {
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/services/${id}`)
    window.location.reload();
}
loadElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
    page++
    getDataJson()
})
function addFavorite(id) {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/favorites?serviceId=${id}`)
        .then(response => {
            axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/services/${id}`)
                .then(response => {
                    axios.post("http://localhost:3000/favorites", response.data);
                });

        });
}
getDataJson()
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    recBoxs.innerHTML = '';

    const searchTerm = search.value.trim();

    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/services?title_like=${searchTerm}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            arr.push(data);
            data.forEach(element => {
                recBoxs.innerHTML += `
                <div class="recent-box">
                <i onclick="addFavorite(${element.id})" class="fa-regular fa-heart" ></i>
                <div class="recent-image"><img src="${element.images}" alt="Image"></div>
                <div class="rec-box-p">${element.date}</div>
                <div class="rec-box-h2">${element.title}</div>
                <div class = "rec-box-btns">
                 <button class="delete" onclick="boxsDelete(${element.id})">
                 <i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
                 <button class = "update"><a href = "./update.html?id=${element.id}" target = "_blank"><i class="fa-solid fa-pencil"></i></a></button>
                 <button class = "cart"><a href = "./details.html?id=${element.id}"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></a></button>
                </div>
            </div>
                `;
            });
            search.value=''
            return arr.flat();
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
});`enter code here`
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).